# Cleanest way to merge two same-shape arrays in Numpy

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

We have some arrays of the same shape and want to merge them.

By "merge", I mean output a new array with the sum of each i,j in each of the arrays in each position.

```
import numpy as np
first = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
second = np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])
third = np.array([[3,3],[3,3]])
```

The result should be:

```
[[6,6],
[6,6]]
```

Here's my code...but is there a cleaner way? I can't seem to find a built-in method:

```
def merge_arrays(arrays):
    output = arrays[0]
    for a in arrays[1:]:
        for i,row in enumerate(a):
            for j,col in enumerate(row):
                output[i,j] += a[i,j]
    return output

merge_arrays([first, second, third])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just `output = first + second + third` or `np.sum([first, second, third], axis=0)`.

Comment: Damned, you did beat me by seconds since you did know the answer while i had to try it in ipython :D

Comment: @KlausWarzecha - I usually get burned when I don't test things out first!  (And I actually did this time, too... Forgot the `axis=0` when I first typed it.)

Comment: @Joe Kington Yes, i saw you editing while i had the simple addition working and was still stumbling over the syntax of np.sum()